# File Upload Regularexpression

Tags: regex

If someone knows please help me to build a regular expression that will valid
- no special characters allow in the file name
- only MS Word file can be uploaded (.docx,.doc, excel, ppt, etc)
- file name can not be more than 80 characters
Thanks

Comment: I'd check the mimetype of the file if I were you. it doesn't take much to upload an executable with a .doc extension. also, forcing your users to follow a certain filename format before uploading seems a bit unwieldy. unless you have a specific reason for this I would just manually clean the filename after uploading.

Comment: @nkotb: Did any of these work for you?

Comment: I've provided a solution below that's much safer than just matching the file extension with a regex, otherwise you'll be in danger, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

What language? Try this:

```
/^[A-Za-Z][A-Za-z0-9_ ]\.(docx|doc|xls|ppt|etc)$/
```

and then check length separately. You'll need to extend/edit the suffix list (etc is obviously not a legit suffix. :)

Comment: Yes, there's a whole level of additional checking that should go on before accepting a file. But, of course, that's beyond the scope of this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-z0-9A-Z-\s*]{1,80}\.(docx|doc|excel|ppt)
```

Add whatever file extensions you need seperated by |

Comment: Need to escape the final hyphen, and the total filename length was to be 80. Also, this will actually allow for names much greater than 80 because it will match 80 chars in the middle of the string, and the string may be several hundred characters long. Easy fixes, though.

Answer (score 0):

All credits go to [finalwesites.com](http://www.finalwebsites.com/snippets.php?id=7), I've tweaked their demo file to fit your needs.
Live demo (without the tweak) at http://www.finalwebsites.com/demos/php_file_upload.php

```
<?php
require dirname(__FILE__).'/upload_class.php'; // Download it @ http://pastebin.com/zAsn8V6R
$folder = dirname(__FILE__)."/upload/"; // "upload" is the folder for the uploaded files (you have to create this folder)

function select_files($dir) {
    // removed in ver 1.01 the globals 
    $teller = 0;
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        $mydir = "<p>These are the files in the directory:</p>\n";
        $mydir .= "<form name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">\n";
        $mydir .= "  <select name=\"file_in_folder\">\n";
        $mydir .= "    <option value=\"\" selected>...\n";
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            $files[] = $file;
        }
        closedir($handle); 
        sort($files);
        foreach ($files as $val) {
            if (is_file($dir.$val)) { // show only real files (ver. 1.01)
                $mydir .= "    <option value=\"".$val."\">";
                $mydir .= (strlen($val) > 30) ? substr($val, 0, 30)."...\n" : $val."\n";
                $teller++;  
            }
        }
        $mydir .= "  </select>";
        $mydir .= "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"download\" value=\"Download\">";
        $mydir .= "</form>\n";
    }
    if ($teller == 0) {
        echo "No files!";
    } else { 
        echo $mydir;
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
    $fullPath = $folder.$_POST['file_in_folder'];
    if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "rb")) {
        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath); 
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]); 
        switch ($ext) {
            case "pdf":
            header("Content-type: application/pdf");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            break;
            case "docx":
            header("Content-type: application/docx");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            break;
            case "doc":
            header("Content-type: application/doc");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            break;
            case "xls":
            header("Content-type: application/xls");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            break;
            case "ppt":
            header("Content-type: application/ppt");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            break;
            case "txt":
            header("Content-type: application/txt"); 
            header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
            break;
            case "odt":
            header("Content-type: application/odt"); 
            header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
            break;
            default;
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        }
        header("Content-length: $fsize");
        header("Cache-control: private"); 
        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
            echo $buffer;
        }
    }
    fclose ($fd);
    exit;
}
function del_file($file) {
    $delete = @unlink($file); 
    clearstatcache();
    if (@file_exists($file)) { 
        $filesys = eregi_replace("/","\\",$file); 
        $delete = @system("del $filesys");
        clearstatcache();
        if (@file_exists($file)) { 
            $delete = @chmod ($file, 0775); 
            $delete = @unlink($file); 
            $delete = @system("del $filesys");
        }
    }
}
function get_oldest_file($directory) {
    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (is_file($directory.$file)) { // add only files to the array (ver. 1.01)
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        if (count($files) <= 12) {
            return;
        } else {
            foreach ($files as $val) {
                if (is_file($directory.$val)) {
                    $file_date[$val] = filemtime($directory.$val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    asort($file_date, SORT_NUMERIC);
    reset($file_date);
    $oldest = key($file_date);
    return $oldest;
}

$max_size = 1024*2000; // the max. size for uploading = 2000 KB, change this to fit your needs
$my_upload = new file_upload;

$my_upload->upload_dir = $folder;
$my_upload->extensions = array(".docx", ".ppt", ".doc", ".pdf", ".xls", ".odt", ".txt"); // specify the allowed extensions here


if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $my_upload->the_temp_file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $my_upload->the_file = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $my_upload->http_error = $_FILES['upload']['error'];
    $my_upload->replace = (isset($_POST['replace'])) ? $_POST['replace'] : "n";
    $my_upload->do_filename_check = (isset($_POST['check'])) ? $_POST['check'] : "n"; 
    if ($my_upload->upload()) {
        $latest = get_oldest_file($folder);
        del_file($folder.$latest);
    }
}

?> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Demo: File upload/download and open directory</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
label {
    font: 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 5px 0 0;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:120px;
}
#main {
    width:350px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
input {
    margin-left:5px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
  <h2 style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">Demo page:</h2>
  <p align="center">(File upload/download and open directory)</p>
  <p>Max. filesize: <b><?php echo $max_size/1024; ?> KB</b><br>
  <?php 
  $ext = "Allowed extensions are: <b>";
  foreach ($my_upload->extensions as $val) {
      $ext .=  ltrim($val, ".").", ";
  } 
  echo rtrim($ext, ", ")."</b>";
  ?>
  </p>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_size; ?>">
    <center><input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" size="25"></center>
    <label for="replace">Replace?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="replace" id="replace" value="y"><br clear="all">
    <label for="check">Validate filename ?</label>
    <input name="check" type="checkbox" id="check" value="y" checked>
    <br clear="all">
    <center><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"></center>
  </form>
  <p style="margin-top:20px;color:#FF0000;"><?php echo $my_upload->show_error_string(); ?></p>
  <?php echo select_files($folder); ?>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```